# How to take a really wide image (25020px by 238px) with frames, show one frame at a time, then move to a new frame based on the touch location?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm new to iOS programming so sorry if this is simple.

I have an image that is 25020px wide and 238px high with 60 frames (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIJOY.jpg), each frame is 417px wide and 238px high. I want to show the first frame then move to the next frame based on the touch location over the image.

I've been reading around and I think it's possible with UIImageView initiated with a frame CGRect but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Can someone guide me in the right direction please? Thanks.

Comment: what you want to do is `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, and height)]; you want to change the x, y, width, and height of the CGRectMake method and that is how you initiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project:
https://github.com/dhoerl/PhotoScrollerNetwork

([Credit to David Hoerl who is a member of this site also!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090725/983912))

The idea is to use `CATiledLayer` to tile the large image, and then use a scroll view to move between tiles. Your use case seems very simple (move from tile to tile).