# Loading a big image/file onto UIWebView - memory management problems

Tags: ios, image, memory-management, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I get a large (3900x2613 px) base64 encoded JPEG image from a webservice. I decode it and present it on a `UIWebView`.  Now I get

> Received memory warning.

in my sample app, the real app gets killed from iOS. This is what I do:

```
webView = new UIWebView();
webView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
View.AddSubview(webView);
NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
viewsDictionary["webView"] = webView;
View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|[webView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));

string image = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("big_image.txt"); // 11,8 MB encoded (origin image 8,9 MB)
double image_size = (double)(image.Length * sizeof (Char)) / 1024 / 1024;
Console.WriteLine("base64 encoded image size: " + Math.Round(image_size, 2) + " MB"); // 22,59 MB
NSData documentData = new NSData(image, NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine("documentData size: " + NSByteCountFormatter.Format((long)documentData.Length, NSByteCountFormatterCountStyle.File)); // 8,9 MB

webView.LoadData(documentData, "image/jpeg", "", new NSUrl("/"));
```

I’m using Xamarin.iOS and this code is in C#, but it should only demonstrate what I do and you can of course use Objective-C/Swift in your answers. So this should not be limited to Xamarin.iOS but to iOS in general.

Now I used instruments and here are some stats:

```
100 MB (Activity Monitor - Real memory usage of my app)  
21 MB (Leaks - Persistent Bytes)
```

In *Leaks/Allocations* I also see a big `Malloc`:

```
8,48 MB Foundation - NSData initWithBase64EncodedObject  
8,48 MB JavaScriptCore - WTF::fastMalloc(unsigned long)
```

The image gets displayed, but zooming doesn’t work correct with this approach (but this is not the question asked here). So in my little sample app I’m nearly hitting the limits of an iPhone 4S. The real app crashes. Safari can open the image without problems.

What are my options here? What should one do in general if file size gets too big? And what if not only images are concerned but rather all file types the `UIWebView` supports?

Comment: Can web service return multiple images of different sizes? If so, the app can request different image based on user gestures. Obviously the user cannot view the full resolution image at once on small screen.

Comment: see "Simplified Scrolling with Tiled Images" (http://www.teachersdoor.com/TipsNTricks/simpleTile.html) . The source is not mine.

Comment: Also pls check other similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447584/display-large-images-on-ios-without-precut-tiles

Comment: @jkr: Currently the web service can only return the full size image. Thanks for the links I'll have a look into it. The most solutions only concerns images. The webview can display other things too (pdf, docx, rtf, ...). Does the webview take care of this by itself? Or do you need an extra viewer for each type and implement a tiling algorithm?